# grep or awk to extact xml from log based on search string

Tags: linux, awk, grep, xml

I have a log file which has XMLs being logged. I need to search and extract all XML's that have a specific string in the any one of the nodes.

e.g. the log file will have mulitple xml's containing the search param.

```
randomlogentry1
randomlogentry2
Printing XML:<CreateDataABC>
    <Tag1>searchparam</Tag1>
</CreateDataABC>
randomlogentry3
randomlogentry4
randomlogentry5
Printing XML: <DataCreatedABC>
       <TagA>otherparam</TagA>
       <TagB>searchparam</TagB>
       <TagC>otherparam</TagC>
    </DataCreatedABC>
randomlogentry6
randomlogentry7
```

The expected output is the two XML's printed on console or written to seperate files.

XML1:

```
<CreateDataABC>
     <Tag1>searchparam</Tag1>
</CreateDataABC>
```

XML2:

```
<DataCreatedABC>
     <TagA>otherparam</TagA>
     <TagB>searchparam</TagB>
     <TagC>otherparam</TagC>
</DataCreatedABC>
```

The position of 'searchparam' in a XML is never fixed and the only constants are the 'ABC' string and the 'searchparam'.

I thought to use sed to extract between 2 line numbers for which I tried the following:

1. Search for the searchparam and identify line no.
2. Find the next occurence of ABC and get the line number,

I somehow cant seem to be able to find the previous occurence of ABC from a specific line!!

Has anyone done this before?

EDIT: Updated the example log format and expected output.

Comment: extend your content to show a surrounded parts of the search xml fragment

Comment: Is the log file a well-formed XML file?

Comment: Log file is not an XML its text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Max=`grep -c "^Printing" file.xml`

for count in `seq 1 $Max`
do
    sed -nr '/Printing/H;//,/ABC/G;s/\n(\n[^\n]*){'$count'}$//p'  file.xml | sed 's/Printing XML://' > $count.xml
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the query with more details, what I need to do is to extract the entire XML out of a text log file...

Comment: plz, share the expected output as like I did in my answer.

Comment: have updated the exact output expected

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Siva, as I mentioned, the only constants are 'ABC' and 'searchparam' so I cannot depend on the presence of 'Printing'.

Comment: any comments/improvements on the solution posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I wrote, but I am sure there is a shorter and more elegant way of doing this.

```
searchstring=searchparam
filename=test.log
pattern1=ABC

linenums=($(grep -n "${searchstring}" ${filename} | awk -F":" '{print $1}'))
len=${#linenums[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ));
do
  currentline=${linenums[$i]}
  relativeendlinearray=($(tail -n +${currentline} ${filename} | grep -n "${pattern1}" | awk -F":" '{print $1}'))
  actualendline=$(($currentline+${relativeendlinearray[0]}-1))

  index=$currentline
  while [ $index -ne 0 ]
        do
        found=`sed "${index}q;d" ${filename} | grep "${pattern1}"`
        if [ -n "$found" ]; then
            actualstartline=$index
            break;
        fi
        index=$[$index-1]
  done

  if [ -n "$found" ]; then
        echo ""
  else
        echo "Log break detected, content across multiple files"
  fi

  echo "Start Line" ${actualstartline}
  echo "Current Line" ${currentline}
  echo "End Line" ${actualendline}
  sed -n "${actualstartline},${actualendline}p" ${filename}
done
```